# SQL COALESCE not working

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

This query runs great when there are records, but when there are no records - I would expect to see 0 for the output under equiptype - but it does not work - any clues... Using Oracle 11g

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(SUBSTR(LINK1,-3,3) as INTEGER), 0) equiptype
FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1
WHERE SUBSTR(LINK1,4,4)='2016' AND SUBSTR(LINK1,10,3)='033'
ORDER BY SUBSTR(LINK1,-3,3) DESC;
```

Comment: `COALESCE()` is working fine - it returns the first non-`NULL` value in the set you've passed in.  If you are getting no results, there are no values to be `NULL`.  Not getting any results is not the same as getting a `NULL` value.

Comment: The uery returns no rows if there are no matches.  Why would it return a row with a value of `0`, if the `where` clause filters everything out?

Comment: Or, to put it another way - your COALESCE is evaluated against every row returned. No row returned = no COALESCE evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You have no rows returned in case WHERE SUBSTR(LINK1,4,4)<>'2016' AND SUBSTR(LINK1,10,3)<>'033', so you get no results for these rows. You, probably, want to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN SUBSTR(LINK1,4,4)='2016' AND SUBSTR(LINK1,10,3)='033'
       THEN CAST(SUBSTR(LINK1,-3,3)
       ELSE 0 END equiptype 
  FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Are you sure you want to read the whole table?